# Import Doesn't Seem to Work On Pages with Search

Tags: import.io

I have been trying to scrape TireRack.com to find all their product names, images, sizes, and prices, but nothing seems to work. I believe this is because the "main" tire page is simply a search box where one has to input tire dimensions, vehicle model, etc. I was wondering if there was a way around this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Connector to simulate a search on the website or create a Crawler and train it on the pages that you'd like to scrape, like [BLIZZAK DM-V2](http://www.tirerack.com/tires/tires.jsp?tireMake=Bridgestone&tireModel=Blizzak%20DM-V2), then you can use urls like [Our Catalog](http://www.tirerack.com/it/index.jsp) so that it will follow all the available links that matches the pages that you trained.

You can also check these links:

- [Create a Connector](http://support.import.io/knowledgebase/articles/247567-create-a-connector)
- [Create a Crawler](http://support.import.io/knowledgebase/articles/247570-create-a-crawler-extract-data-from-an-entire-web)